# RStudio: Summation of two datasets of different lengths

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I have two datasets A and B:

Dataset A (called Sales) has the following data:

```
ID   Person    Sales
1      1        100
2      2        300
3      3        400
4      4        200
5      5        50
```

Dataset B (called Account_Scenarios) has the following data (Note- there are a lot more rows in dataset B I have just included the first 6):

```
ID   Scenario Person    Upkeep
1        1      1        -10
2        1      2        -200
3        2      1        -150
4        3      4        -50
5        3      3        -100
6        4      5        -500
```

I want to add a column called 'Profit' in dataset B such that I am able to see the profit per person per scenario (Profit = Sales + Upkeep). For example as below:

```
ID   Scenario Person    Upkeep   Profit
1        1      1        -10       90
2        1      2        -200      100
3        2      1        -150      -50
4        3      4        -50       150
5        3      3        -100      300
6        4      5        -500      -450
```

What is the best way to do this? I am new to R and trying use an aggregate function but it requires the arguments to be the same length.

```
Account_Scenarios$Profit <- aggregate(Sales[,c('Sales')], Account_Scenarios[,c('Upkeep')], by=list(Sales$Person), 'sum')
```

Comment: Looks to me that you first need to `sum` within "Person"'s and then `merge` but at the moment your example and description of the task are too sketchy to offer an answer. See if you can [edit] the question to improve it. See [MCVE] and search on "How to make a great reproducible R question" for guidance and code tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Sales$Person` have only unique values, you can:

```
Account_Scenarios$Profit=Account_Scenarios$Upkeep-Sales$Sales[sapply(Account_Scenarios$Person,function(x)which(Sales$Person==x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `left_join` the two datasets base `Person` variable, then calculate the profit:

```
library(tidyverse)
A <- A %>% select(Person, Sales) # Only need the two variables for the join
df <- left_join(B, A, by = "Person") %>%
    mutate(Profit = Sales + Upkeep)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be using `sqldf` library (a sql style `join`):

```
library(sqldf)

A <- data.frame(Person=1:5, Sales=c(100,300,400,200,50)) 
B <- data.frame(Scenario=c(1,1,2,3,3,4), Person=c(1,2,1,4,3,5), Upkeep=c(-10,-200,-150,-50,-100,-500))
B <- sqldf("SELECT B.*, A.Sales + B.Upkeep as Profit FROM B JOIN A on B.Person = A.Person")
```